# Select_tag passing params through search rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, parameters

I have an text_field to make search. I used to make one type of search, but now I want to use more than one function to search, and I put a select_tag with the search field.

```
<%= form_tag(search_project_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Nome/Número do Projeto" %>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>

    <%= select_tag(params[:search_type], 
      options_for_select(["Ativos", "Inativos", "Orçamentos"], "Ativos"),
      {class: "form-control"}) %>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There's 3 types of search, and 3 functions do be used.

```
def self.searchA(search)
  s = "%"+search+"%"
  self.where("ativo = true").where("lower(descricao) LIKE ? OR id_projeto LIKE ?", s.downcase, s)
end

def self.searchI(search)
  s = "%"+search+"%"
  self.where("ativo = false").where("lower(descricao) LIKE ? OR id_projeto LIKE ?", s.downcase, s)
end

def self.searchO(search)
  s = "%"+search+"%"
  self.where("id_projeto LIKE ?", "O-").where("lower(descricao) LIKE ? OR id_projeto LIKE ?", s.downcase, s)
end
```

How do I pass a params[:search_type] to the controller? There's another way to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: You're going to regret mixing cases like that (I would at least) in the ruby code (you're better off keeping everything snake_case).  Also, you might want to consider using scopes for those search functions (though scope is just a shorthand for what you've got).   Rather than using params[:search_type] in the select tag try just using "search_type" and I think you'll find that will make it available in your params.

Comment: That worked fine! Thanks!!